# java temporary files created but contents write issue

Tags: java, spring

```
package com.studytrails.tutorials.springremotingrmiserver;
import java.lang.Object;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.*;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

public class GreetingServiceImpl implements GreetingService {
    @Override
    public String getGreeting(String name) {

        return "Hello " + name + "!";

    }


       public String getText()
       {
           ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"spring-config-server.xml"});

    Resource resource = appContext.getResource("file:D:\\text\\test.txt");
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
try{

      InputStream is = resource.getInputStream();
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
     File temp=File.createTempFile("output", ".tmp");



      String filePath=temp.getAbsolutePath();
     System.out.println(""+filePath);


      String line;
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(temp));
      //System.out.println(""+filePath);


      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {


          out.println(line);


      }


     String tem=temp.getName();
    //temp.setReadOnly();


      String[] cmd = {"notepad",tem}; 
      Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

      Process proc = runtime.exec(cmd);

      out.close();
      br.close();

 temp.deleteOnExit();

    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
return builder.toString();

       }


    }
```

In the above code creates the temporary file but i am trying to write contents in that file but when the program executed notepad is open with the temporary name but it gives message file not exists do you want to create. i need that temporary file with the text present in the D:\text\test.txt   location. kindly suggest me

Comment: Firstly, i think you should use the `BufferedWriter` to improve efficiency for the IO write operation.       `PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(temp)));` without using that, your `println()` is continuously writing to the file which is highly inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is the updated code that should work. I have writen it as a java program but it is working. Your main problem was you were calling `temp.deleteOnExit();` just after the process open. You have to wait for the process to complete, other wise the main thread will delete the file even before the notepad opens it. Also use `out.write(line);` Hope it helps.

```
String line;
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(temp));

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    out.write(line);
}
out.flush();
out.close();
br.close();

String[] cmd = { "notepad", filePath };
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

Process proc = runtime.exec(cmd);

out.close();
br.close();
try {
    proc.waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
temp.deleteOnExit();
```